# Finding all values of logarithmic function for complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Question:**
Find all the values of $\log{((1 + i)^{πi})}$

**My attempt:**

$\log{((1 + i)^{πi})} = \pi i \log(1+i) = \pi i(\ln|1+i| + i*\arg(1+i))$

$\ln|1+i| = 2, \arg(1+i) = \pi/4 + 2k\pi$

$\therefore \pi i(\ln|1+i| + i*\arg(1+i)) = \pi i(\ln\sqrt2 + i(\pi/4 + 2k\pi))
= \pi i\ln\sqrt2 - \pi(\pi/4 + 2k\pi)$

Could anyone confirm whether it is right or not? If wrong, could you specify the part where it is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. this method is correct and so is the answer.

Comment: If your $\text{log}$ is a complex logarithm, then it's not true in general that $\text{log}(x)^{a} = a\text{log}(x)$ especially when $a$ is a complex number.